# SIUnitx Unit Grouping

Tags: siunitx, grouping, units

Is there any `siunitx` options to manage grouping of units when `per-mode=symbol` is active?  Or, is there a better way to handle this?

Manually inserting parenthesis works fine (second line).
But, when I define

```
\DeclareSIUnit\BracrOpen{(}%
\DeclareSIUnit\BracrClose{)}%
```

and replace the `(` and `)` with `\BracrOpen` and `\BracrClose`, I get wacky results (third line).   Seems as if I can remedy this with an addtional brace group (fourth line), but would be preferable to not need this additional brace group if it all possible.

I have used `\DeclareSIUnit` to define many ohter units and have not seen this issue, so wondeirng what is causing this wacky result in this situation.

[image]

### Notes:

- I would prefer to use a macro as that allows other processing of the symbol separate from its usage.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}%

\DeclareSIUnit\BracrOpen{\mathopen{(}}%
\DeclareSIUnit\BracrClose{\mathclose{)}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    g_0 
        &= \SI{9.81}{\meter\per\second\squared} \\
        &= \SI{35.3}{(\kilo\meter\per\hour)\per\second} \\
        &= \SI{35.3}{\BracrOpen\kilo\meter\per\hour\BracrClose\per\second} 
            \qquad\text{\textcolor{red}{Incorrect!}} \\
        &= \SI{35.3}{\BracrOpen{\kilo\meter\per\hour}\BracrClose{\per\second}} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose the habit of siunitx to group repeated `\per` objects into a parenthetic expression if `per-mode=symbol` is in force is mentioned, admittedly somewhat tersely, at the bottom of p. 38 and the top of p. 39 of the package's user guide. I can't find anything in the user guide that would address your question about managing the grouping of units.

Comment: @Mico" Oh, hadn't seen those, but you are right, they dont' quite help in this situation. I will do the manual grouping (as in the last ouptut line) until a better solution appears.

Comment: There is no 'grouping', there is 'parsing the units in order'. When you add explicit output, such as `(`/`)`, parsing is all turned off and you just get 'whatever you typed'. If you want to do some manual explanation of unit equivalence, you'll need to do it manually: it's out-of-scope for the package

Comment: @JosephWright: Ok. I can understnad it is out of scope of the package, but thought I would check just in case I was missing something.  Still curious as to the cause of the wacky results when using the `\BracrOpen` and `\BracrClose` macros (where the `h` got moved to be _after_ the `\BracrClose` -- see third line of output). I realize I am `abusing` `\DeclareSIUnit` by making the parenthesis SI "units", but don't understand why that breaks things, and don't know a better way (while still searating out the grouping parenthesis).